# Updating cached http request in Angular with RxJS and shareReplay

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've created a service in my Angular app to create a single http call and cache the results using RxJS and shareReplay like this:

```
export class ApiService {

  data$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) { }
  
  loadData(lang:string) {
    this.data$ = this.http.get(APP_ENDPOINT + '?lang=' + lang).pipe(
      shareReplay(1)
    );
  }

  getData() {
    return this.data$;
  }
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to update my `data$` observable if the language in my app changes, as I would need a new http request and pass the `lang` variable in the request.

What is the best approach for 'resetting' the cached `data$` and create a new http call to get the new data for that language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leverage observables/subjects to trigger a new response; something like this:

```js
export class ApiService {
  lang$ = new BehaviorSubject("myDefaultLang");

  data$ = this.lang.pipe(
    switchMap((lang)=> this.http.get(APP_ENDPOINT + '?lang=' + lang)),
    shareReplay(1),
  );

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) { }
  
  loadData(lang:string) {
    this.lang$.next(lang)
  }

  getData() {
    return this.data$;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make `language` an observable, then define your `data$` from `language$`:

```js
export class ApiService {

  private language$ = new BehaviorSubject('en-US');

  data$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) { }
  
  loadData(lang:string) {
    this.data$ = this.language$.pipe(
      switchMap(lang => this.http.get(`${APP_ENDPOINT}?lang=${lang}`),
      shareReplay(1)
    );
  }

  getData() {
    return this.data$;
  }

  setLanguage(language: string) {
    this.language$.next(language);
  }
}
```

Note: since observables are lazy, you don't really need a `getData$` method.  Consumers can simply refer to `data$`.  The act of subscribing is what "gets" the data.

You can define `data$` directly on the component.

```js
export class ApiService {

  private language$ = new BehaviorSubject('en-US');

  data$: Observable<any> = this.language$.pipe(
    switchMap(lang => this.http.get(`${APP_ENDPOINT}?lang=${lang}`),
    shareReplay()
  );

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  setLanguage(language: string) {
    this.language$.next(language);
  }
}
```